# Error on docker build using rancher desktop

Tags: docker, rancher

I use rancher dekstop I'm trying to execute docker build but I got the error:

```
ERROR: error during connect: Get "http://127.0.0.1:2375/_ping": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2375: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

But rancher desktop is up and running.

Could someone help me?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

After remove a variable on System Variable,called DOCKER_HOST. The error was fixed.